# Layer.match is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

so i work at a startup building a backend web app using the nestJs framework (is slightly based on express)  and typeorm for our Db . So we recently ran into an issue where  the app literally crashes every time  an error is thrown i.e an incorrect password 
.the error below :

```
TypeError: layer.match is not a function
at matchLayer (/home/imuchene/apps/DocuflowApi/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:574:18)
at next (/home/imuchene/apps/DocuflowApi/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:220:15)
at Function.handle (/home/imuchene/apps/DocuflowApi/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
at Function.handle (/home/imuchene/apps/DocuflowApi/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:174:10)
at Server.app (/home/imuchene/apps/DocuflowApi/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:39:9)
at Server.emit (events.js:187:15)
at Server.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:672:12)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:109:17)
```

now for context we're using the Error  class on javascript, even though we think that this is not the issue and rather the routing mechanism of expressjs crashes after the error is thrown , also its worth noting that our application runs fine locally but once deployed on the vm it causes the issue.

Comment: I just started getting this error on an express/apollo setup

Comment: we solved it well not really solved but did a quick hack  by cleaning the instance of the app in the vm and  redeploying it which now works. we now think the issue might be caused by the deployment scripts we use which does the following : sends the now fully transpilled code (in dist) to the vm, does an automated npm install in there and imports some other secured files we use

Comment: I just got this error and I have no idea how to fix it. Re-deplying the app didn't work

Comment: @bryan does your app work locally?

Comment: do you know what version of node you were running?

Comment: Can you please show a minimal code sample that reliably causes the error? We can't determine much from a stack trace that leads, ultimately, to a sub-sub dependency.

Comment: Maybe, Try to update nodeJS

Comment: this might be relevan tl;dr - try to upgrade @sentry/node version: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3916